# Why does /tikz/x in a scope work but /tikz/y have no effect?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to set the `/tikz/x` and `/tikz/y` properties within a `{scope}` in order to perform a local transformation.
It appears that the change to `x` is working just fine, but the change to `y` seems to be doing nothing at all.

What's going on here?

```
\documentclass[border=1in]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit,calc}
\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{dimetric2}=[x={(0.935cm,-0.118cm)},z={(0cm,0.943cm)},y={(0.354cm,0.312cm)}]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[dimetric2]
        \draw[black,-latex] (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[right] {$e_x$};
        \draw[black,-latex] (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0) node[above right] {$e_y$};
        \draw[black] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1);
        % y= argument seems to do nothing
        \begin{scoped}[x={(0.8, 0.6, 0)}, y={(-0.6, 0.8, 0)}]
            \draw[thick,green] (0, 0, 0) -- (2, 0, 0);
            \draw[thick,red] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 2, 0);
        \end{scoped}
        % drawn without y=: fails identically
        \begin{scoped}[x={(0.8, 0.6, 0)}]
            \draw[thick,green] (0, 0, 1) -- (2, 0, 1);
            \draw[thick,red] (0, 0, 1) -- (0, 2, 1);
        \end{scoped}
        \draw[black,-latex] (0,0,1) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$n_o$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, both green lines seem to render correct, but neither red line does:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you wrote **"scoped"** instead of **"scope"**. The environment is called `scope` but the command is called `\scoped`.

I marked the changes with `%<--`

```
   \documentclass[border=1in]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit,calc}
    \begin{document}
        \tikzstyle{dimetric2}=[x={(0.935cm,-0.118cm)},z={(0cm,0.943cm)},y={(0.354cm,0.312cm)}]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[dimetric2]
            \draw[black,-latex] (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[right] {$e_x$};
            \draw[black,-latex] (0,-3,0) -- (0,7,0) node[above right] {$e_y$};
            \draw[black] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1);
            % y= argument seems to do nothing
            \begin{scope}[x={(0.8, 0.6)}, y={(-0.6, 0.8, 0)}]%<-- scope 
                \draw[thick,green] (0, 0, 0) -- (2, 0, 0);
                \draw[thick,red] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 2, 0);
            \end{scope}%<-- scope (and not scoped !)
            % drawn without y=: fails identically
            \begin{scope}[x={(0.8, 0.6, 0)}]%<-- scope 
                \draw[thick,green] (0, 0, 1) -- (2, 0, 1);
                \draw[thick,red] (0, 0, 1) -- (0, 2, 1);
            \end{scope}%<-- scope 
            \draw[black,-latex] (0,0,1) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$n_o$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Whoops! This still doesn't work right though - it seems the coordinate for `y=` is computed using the new value for `x=`, rather than taking effect simultaneously. Is there an easy way to avoid that?

Comment: Normally, the x, y and z are given in two dimensions. Why do you want to give them in 3d? TikZ doesn't have true 3D.

Comment: Tikz doesn't need true 3d for me - I just want it to keep track of my 3 unit vectors, and let me transform then in `scoped` blocks.

Comment: Define your 3 vectors with two coordinates for example `x={(0.2,.5)}` and not 3 coordinates. When x, y and z are so defined, you will be able to place points in this picture by giving 3 coordinates `(1,2,3)`.

Comment: I'm defining my `x=` in terms of 3 coordines in order to reuse the definitions in `dimetric2`

Comment: And what makes you say it's not working?

Comment: Setting `x=(1,1,0),y=(-1,1,0)` should result in orthogonal lines in the 3d space, but results in `y` being set to `-1*(1,1,0)+(0,1,0)=(0,2,0)` because settings are applied sequentially not simultaneously.

Comment: @Eric The question of the effect of the scope has been resolved, changes to `y` now have an effect.  You say it's not the right one, so it's a new problem. Ask a new question with an MWE that highlights this new problem.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for catching my typo. Is there ever any reason to use `\begin{scoped}`?

Comment: `\begin{scoped}` does not exist with TikZ, TikZ only defines the `\begin{scope}` environment or the `\scoped{}` command. If you write *\begin{scoped}*, there is a syntax error. Scopes are very useful when you want to color the inside of a piece of figure, or when you want to move a figure, and so on.

Comment: I got no syntax error with `\begin{scoped}` - perhaps another package translated it to `\scoped`?

Comment: @Eric I didn't get a syntax error either (but this is one from TikZ's point of view since it didn't work).  If the parser you indicated syntax error, you could have corrected it. What's going on with the parser here?  Was there confusion between the `\scoped{}` command and the imaginary  `scoped` environment? 
It's an interesting question to ask, and one that TeX specialists will certainly be able to answer since TikZ is written in TeX.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)